# polymorphic association, has_one and HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicThroughError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I'm working on a polymorphic association problem, and I'm not quite sure where to go with this.

Here is my current model setup:

```
class Rfq < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :parts_attributes
    has_many :parts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :mailer_parts
    belongs_to :rfq
    belongs_to :partable, :polymorphic => true
    has_one :mailer, :through => :partable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailer
end

class Mailer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :address
    has_one :part, :as => :partable  # Should/could this be belongs_to?
end
```

When I go to the edit page for an Rfq in a browser, I see this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicThroughError in Rfqs#edit
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Part#mailer' which goes through the polymorphic association 'Part#partable'.
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:   <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
3:   <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
4:   <p>Part Information: </p>
5:   <%= f.fields_for :mailer do |builder| %>
6:     <%= render 'mailer_fields', :f => builder %>
7:   <% end %>
8:   <%= link_to 'Add Mailer Part', '#', :class => "add_mailer_part" %>
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies, as I'm not trying to do a has_many relationship anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the Part model.  You have your `has_one` association through a polymorphic `belongs_to`.

I have no answer for you, yet... but that answers your question.  I think it's just a poorly labeled constant or one they reuse for guys like us trying to do what they don't/can't want.

On the surface I think it's because the DB doesn't have a `partable` column, but `partable_id` and `partable_type`.